# how can i make function execute after one function is finish executing?

Tags: vue.js

i know the question does not make sense with the body but i think it is connected somehow.

this is the variable and function from another script:

```
 let data = ref([]);
    const logIn = (email_address,password) => {
      // console.log(payload);
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        api
          .get("api.php", {params: {email_address: email_address, password: password}})
          .then((response) => {

           data.value = response.data.data;

            }
    
    
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            reject(error);
          });
      });
    };
```

and i imported it to this script:

```
import {
  logIn,data,
} from "../../../composable/taaraComposable";
```

in this script, for example I have this function:

```
  let logInTaara = (pay1,pay2) => {
        logIn(pay1,pay2);

       console.log(data);
      
        };
```

actually the console data have the response data.

```
RefImpl {__v_isShallow: false, dep: Set(1), __v_isRef: true, _rawValue: undefined, _value: undefined}
dep
: 
Set(1) {ReactiveEffect}
__v_isRef
: 
true
__v_isShallow
: 
false
_rawValue
: 
[{…}]
_value
: 
Proxy(Array) {0: {…}}
value
: 
Proxy(Array)
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

and this is what inside the `_rawValue`
_rawValue
:

```
Array(1)
0
: 
Bio
: 
"qrqwer"
birth_date
: 
"0000-00-00"
brgy_name
: 
"busay"
city_municipality
: 
"daraga"
civil_status
: 
"single"
date_archieve
: 
"0000-00-00"
date_created
: 
"0000-00-00"
email_address
: 
"mikocoral05@gmail.com"
first_name
: 
"Michael"
id
: 
1
last_name
: 
"Corral"
middle_name
: 
"Millares"
occupation
: 
"student"
password
: 
"qwer"
phone_number
: 
9526487987
province
: 
"albay"
sex
: 
"male"
street
: 
"purok 2"
suffix
: 
"jrasdasd"
user_id
: 
2
user_image
: 
"49914692_2274892909503020_6776713521204822016_n.jpg"
username
: 
"sadf"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

the real problem is

if i console the `data._rawValue`

```
console.log(data._rawValue);
```

it showing nothing.

```
it shows null
```

but if the function is `click twice` the

```
 console.log(data._rawValue);
```

have output.

```
[{…}]
0
: 
{id: 1, user_id: 2, user_image: '49914692_2274892909503020_6776713521204822016_n.jpg', first_name: 'Michael', middle_name: 'Millares', …}
length
: 
1
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
```

how can i make it happen at the first click of the function the `data._rawValue` has value than clicking it twice?

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . You need to use promises but it's unknown how they need to be applied to your code

Comment: Can you change it so logIn returns `data`? That would be the most intuitive.

Comment: i will edit the body. hope it will be understandable

Comment: hello guys i edit it already.